# Cannot get is_valid() to go back to template with bound form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view), it says

> "We call the form’s is_valid() method; if it’s not True, we go back to
> the template with the form. This time the form is no longer empty
> (unbound) so the HTML form will be populated with the data previously
> submitted, where it can be edited and corrected as required."

I am trying to get this behaviour to work.

In views.py:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('auctions/test.html')

    else:
        form = TestForm()
        return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {'form': form})
```

In forms.py:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    testnumber = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=1)
```

In test.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'auctions:test' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, when I submit the form with a number that is more than 1 digit, `is_valid()` evaluates to `False`. When that happens, the docs says the template should be rendered with the bound form and the error. Instead, nothing happens, and I get `ValueError: The view auctions.views.test didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Is return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {'form': form}) supposed to be tabbed in the last line of the code views.py

Comment: @AyanSh No. Yep. That was it. If you want to post an answer I can accept. Can't believe I've been struggling with this so long.

Comment: Ok, ill post the answer np

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the last line of your views.py file is indented.

Instead of:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('auctions/test.html')

    else:
        form = TestForm()
        return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {'form': form})
```

It should be:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('auctions/test.html')

    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {'form': form})
```